# Induction for finite series associativity

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Given this definition of finite series: [image]

I want to prove this statement by induction:

[image]

I tried going up starting from $n=m$, but I don't know how to show that it holds in the base case. I also tried starting from $n=p$ and going backwards, but couldn't quite make that work either.

How can this be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not asked to prove this for $n=p$ because the question specifically states that $n$ is less than $p$.  However, It might actually be easier if you do start at $n=p$, and this would still be correct since you would have proved more than is asked.  The statement for $n=p$ is
$$\sum_{i=m}^p a_i +\sum_{i=p+1}^p a_i=\sum_{i=m}^p a_i\ ;$$
the second sum on the left hand side is zero (by the first part of your definition, since $p<p+1$), and so the result is true.

You can complete the induction by working backwards, exactly as you have suggested.

Alternatively, start with $n=m-1$ (again proving more than was asked) and work forwards.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using induction on $n$, you could instead use induction on $p$: then the base case would be $p = n+1$, and the inductive case would fall out fairly easily.